# operator new syntax for array of pointers

Tags: c++

I have run into the following code

```
int main() {
    int **objects; 
    objects=new (int(*[10])); // seems to be equal to new int*[10];
    delete[] objects;
    return 0;
}
```

I have not managed to parse the line "new (int(*[10]))".
I am used to standard syntax "new int*[10]" and totally surprised with the one above.

Could you explain why this "new (int(*[10]))" is correct and does the same as "new int*[10]"?

Comment: `new int*[10]` compiles fine for me. But `delete objects[];` should be `delete[] objects;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the two grammatical constructions at work, straight from `[C++11: 5.3.4]`:

> *new-expression*:
>     `::`<sub>opt</sub>`new` *new-placement*<sub>opt</sub> *new-type-id* *new-initializer*<sub>opt</sub>
>     `::`<sub>opt</sub>`new` *new-placement*<sub>opt</sub>`(` *type-id* `)` *new-initializer*<sub>opt</sub>

You're used to the former but have encountered the latter. Let's take a closer look at that one; what is *type-id* and how does it differ from *new-type-id*?

> `[C++11: 5.3.4/3]:` The *new-type-id* in a *new-expression* is the longest possible sequence of *new-declarators.* *[ Note:* this prevents ambiguities between the declarator operators &, &&, *, and [] and their expression counterparts. *—end note ] [ Example:*
>
> ```
> new int * i; // syntax error: parsed as (new int*) i, not as (new int)*i
> ```
>
> The * is the pointer declarator and not the multiplication operator. *—end example ]*

So, you see, this is why `new (int(*[10]))` is valid but `new int(*[10])` is not: the outer parenthesis allows `5.3.4/3` to kick in.

This is actually addressed in the following passage, as is the validity of the inner parenthesis in an example *very* similar to yours:

> `[C++11: 5.3.4/4]:` *[ Note:* parentheses in a *new-type-id* of a *new-expression* can have surprising effects. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> new int(*[10])(); // error
> ```
>
> is ill-formed because the binding is
>
> ```
> (new int) (*[10])(); // error
> ```
>
> Instead, the explicitly parenthesized version of the new operator can be used to create objects of compound types (3.9.2):
>
> ```
> new (int (*[10])());
> ```
>
> allocates an array of 10 pointers to functions (taking no argument and returning `int`.) *—end example ]*
>
> *—end note ]*

In your case, although you are using pointers rather than pointers-to-functions (note the additional `()` in the above quote examples), your `int (*[10])` is still a compound type and thus the same logic applies.

Finally, `int (*[10])` is the same as `int* [10]` because *it just is*: that's how the syntax of *type-id* constructions works:

```
<tomalak> << TYPE_DESC<int (*[10])>;
<geordi> array of 10 pointers to integers
<tomalak> << TYPE_DESC<int* [10]>;
<geordi> Same output.
```

*(using [geordi](http://www.eelis.net/geordi/))*